# Not able to run the multiple class in single appium xml file

Tags: android, xml, appium, testcase

I did tried the following code with XML but not able to run the TC001 and TC002 together. If I run the TC001 only then the test case is passed but when both Test cases are run together then TC001 always fails. Help me out if anyone can.

Also I tried adding the same code in TC001 and TC002, though TC001 always fails and TC002 passes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">  
<suite name="test_suite">  
<test name="TC001">  
<classes>  

<class name ="test.TC001"/>
<class name ="test.TC002"/>

</classes>
</test>
 
 <!-- Test -->  
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: normally, it should pass. if the issue is still not resolved ping here back.

Comment: Still facing the same issue, not able to run both TC001 and TC002 together.

Comment: mail on chetan66199gmailcom